# Is there a need for die; after print json_encode() when responding to api calls?

Tags: php, json, web-services, yii, die

I'm creating various 'my version' of web services. Basically, it's a yii controller with lots of actions.. each action is as follow

```
public function actionNameOfWebService()
{
   if(isset($_POST))
   {
      // do some processing, when I have a result... I do .. 
      print CJSON::encode('result.');
   }
   else
   {
      print CJSON::encode('only post methods allowed');
   }
}
```

Lots of those actions are in one particular controller. Everything's working fine..before I go to production, do I need to add a 'die;' statement after every print CJSON::encode statement.

Comment: Use `die()` only when you know, that the script should not continue after the current line.

Comment: You should use `Yii::app()->end();`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't have to but when you add it, you'll be sure that nothing will be printed after JSON, which will break parsers attempts to read that data.

But if you know that there is nothing more, you can skip it.

Comment: So I have a gut feeling there's nothing more. But I was looking at it as more of a precaution. After any print CJSON::encode method.. I know there should be nothing more... it could be that by chance I've missed to check for a condition and the process continues, thus as you mention breaking the receiver end's parser.. So I was thinking if adding die would help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Yii, you should simply use :

```
Yii::app()->end();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#end-detail

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't absolutely need `die` or `exit`. I would argue that using it is a bit of anti-pattern. It breaks encapsulation.

If you have some kind of output buffering set up the `die` might actually be bad. If you're proxying a request `die` will kill the whole process etc. There are more scenarios like this.

Comment: What do you mean by output buffering?

Comment: Output buffering is a feature of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: I want to vote up.. but .. I have no powers! I chose the below answer as the answer, because he answered what I really doubted.. but thanks for the output buffering bit.. I'm going read more about it..

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use `Yii::app()->end();`This is because if you have any debugging output, or profiling output, this will also be included in the response unless you tell the app to finish. Your validation could break if you fail to include this.